# How to clean up keyDown array

Tags: javascript, user-input, keyboard-events, keydown

I'm fiddling around trying to build a game, and added some even listeners to find out which keys are down. I stack 'm up into one array, and use that array to manipulate the game-state.

If this is the wrong way to go about it, feel free to comment on that specifically, but I'm just going to assume for a moment that this is *one* of the ways to Rome.

My question; when someone presses multiple keys at once (or lots of them in the case of PS2 boards) these case might get "stuck" in the array, while not being down.

How would one prune this array, without removing keys that are actually down at that very moment?

```
var keysDown = []; // this is where I toss all they keyCodes

function keyDown(e) {
  e = e || event;
  if (keysDown.indexOf(e.keyCode) < 0) {
    keysDown.push(e.keyCode)
    console.log(keysDown);
  };
};

function keyUp(e) {
  e = e || event;
  if (keysDown.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    keysDown.splice(keysDown.indexOf(e.keyCode), 1);
    console.log(keysDown);
  };
};

document.onkeydown = keyDown;
document.onkeyup = keyUp;
```

.edit: [Fiddled it](http://jsfiddle.net/AboutaDirk/EnVK7/).

Comment: not clear how you think they might get stuck since you remove them on keyup. No way to check if they are `still down` if that's what you are looking for

Comment: They get "stuck" because a keyboard can only handle an x amount of signals at the same time. It's a hardware limitation, which the software will have to deal with. I was just hoping there would be an elegant way of doing this, without making the user press those keys again to remove them manually.

Comment: In my experience, the `keydown` event is fired continuously while the key is pressed down. So just remove it and it'll be added again soon enough if the key is still down.

Comment: That's actually untrue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, with JS this just isn't possible.

The neatest way to handle this is to do nothing.

Alternatively you can consider keeping track of the total number of keys punched in and if it exceeds a certain number (hard to say how many) you could delete the first pressed keys, but that's more like patching a leaking barrel with some tape.